# Images changing sizes between browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website and I temporary images in place made in photoshop, I've re-made these images in illustrator and between chrome and firefox the images are changing sizes (being huge in firefox and small in chrome). I've exported the images to be png and I am using width and max-width on these images.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Post a part of ur code for us to understand how u are using the styles for this images.

Comment: No problem! 
I'm literally just using:
<img style="width: 100%; max-width: 45%;" src="images/animation.png"> That's all my styling on the image itself.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you just using width: 45%? That's what width: 100% and max-width: 45% is ultimately going to do.

Comment: @BrightTime I agree with @Ryan, if u put 100% and then 45% ur 100% is not going work in some browser as 45% will be overwritten. You should probably write in `px` i.e `width: 20px; max-width: 40px`

Comment: When I was on my apprenticeship that was how I was told to approach scaling images on the web!

Comment: @Smit I shall give that a try! :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max-width` can't be less than `width`. The most common way of using `max-width` is like this:

```
.selector {
    width: 1200px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

So, the `width` controls the actual width of the `.selector` but the `max-width` won't let the `.selector` to be wider than `100%` of the `document`. Actually, the way you've written the `max-width`, it's overridden the `width`.

If you're serious about using `width` and also `max-width`, you may write it this way:

```
<img style="width: 45%; max-width: 45%;" src="images/animation.png">
```

In addition,
Inline CSS is not recommended in SEO. If you're keen about it, think it over and also add an alt to the image :-)

Good luck!